# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' ( can't using collect() after distinct() )

Tags: python, pyspark

for rdd is like that:

```
[['Tosa de la Llosada', '42.55129', '1.64243'],
 ['Riu de la Llosada', '42.53619', '1.61625'],
 ['Obaga de la Llosada', '42.54673', '1.6326'],
 ['Emprius de la Llosada', '42.5463', '1.6213'],
 ['Basers de la Llosada', '42.55113', '1.63183'],]
```

Then I tried to using distinct() to eliminate the exact same lines.
so I tried the code below:

```
rdd.map(lambda x:[x[0].lower(),x[1],x[2]]).distinct().collect()
```

Then I got an error message "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"
The complete error information is as below: ( I assume that maybe it was because I was using "distinct()" in a wrong way?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [58], in <module>
----> 1 rdd.map(lambda x:[x[0].lower(),x[1],x[2]]).distinct().collect()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py:950, in RDD.collect(self)
    941 """
    942 Return a list that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
    943 
   (...)
    947 to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.
    948 """
    949 with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 950     sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    951 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py:1309, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1303 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1304     self.command_header +\
   1305     args_command +\
   1306     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1308 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309 return_value = get_return_value(
   1310     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1312 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1313     temp_arg._detach()

File /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File /usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 33.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 33.0 (TID 23) (73b33c0aa869 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 609, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 417, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2146, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 242, in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:703)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:685)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:898)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 609, in process
    out_iter = func(split_index, iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2918, in pipeline_func
    return func(split, prev_func(split, iterator))
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 417, in func
    return f(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2146, in combineLocally
    merger.mergeValues(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 242, in mergeValues
    d[k] = comb(d[k], v) if k in d else creator(v)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:703)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:685)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:498)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.fill(Iterator.scala:1211)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$GroupedIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1217)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda output has a list of values, so you can do this.

```
rdd.map(lambda x: x[0].lower()).distinct().collect()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved my code problem. also a good explanation from a kind mate:  " but I think the reason for lists not working is the following.  Tuples are hashable as their contents cannot change and thus you can calculate a hash value for them. The lists contents can change and thus it is not simple to define hashvalue for them. Why is hashing needed? The distinct does not probably check  that objects are the same but calculates the hash for them and keeps only the ones with different hash. This is much faster than checking actual equality for the more complicated objects or lists."